# convert from JSON to an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am new in javascript, can you please help me convert from JSON format to a normal array

```
             {"data": [
             {"name": "Bhengu","surname":"Nathi"},
             {"name": "Tsunami","surname":"Msipha"},
             { "name": "Fish","surname":"Lee"}
             ]};


             data= [
             {name: Bhengu, surname: Nathi},
             {name: Tsunami, surname: Msipha},
             { name: Fish, surname: Lee}
              ];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `json_decode` function of php

```
$json = '{"data": [{ "name": "Bhengu","surname":"Nathi"}, { "name": "Tsunami","surname":"Msipha"}, { "name": "Fish","surname":"Lee"} ]}';
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

output will be :

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'data' => 
    array
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public 'name' => string 'Bhengu' (length=6)
          public 'surname' => string 'Nathi' (length=5)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'name' => string 'Tsunami' (length=7)
          public 'surname' => string 'Msipha' (length=6)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'name' => string 'Fish' (length=4)
          public 'surname' => string 'Lee' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{"data": [{ "name": "Bhengu","surname":"Nathi"}, { "name": "Tsunami","surname":"Msipha"}, { "name": "Fish","surname":"Lee"} ]};

heredata= [ { name: Bhengu, surname: Nathi}, { name: Tsunami, surname: Msipha},{ name: Fish, surname: Lee} ];
```

you can use  [Json2 script](http://www.json.org/js.html)

you can then run:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);
```

which should give you the array you need as myObject

Comment: The code i've been running does not work on json format and works on this one
heredata= [ 
{ name: Bhengu, surname: Nathi}, 
{ name: Tsunami, surname: Msipha},
{ name: Fish, surname: Lee} ];

Comment: If the question is, I need to convert Json into an array the JSON.Parse sould work. If you want to convert Json into another string format then you will need to parse it yourself. What I think your saying is that you declare an array using heredata= [ { name: Bhengu, surname: Nathi}, { name: Tsunami, surname: Msipha}, { name: Fish, surname: Lee} ]; so heredata is an array! The above example sets myObject as an array also, heredata and myObject are an array of the same type? That said I'm a bit confused by what your actually asking....

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the second parameter `true`, which will force the returned objects to be converted to arrays.

```
$result = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
if (isset($result)) {
  do something here...
}
```

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) entry for detailed use (ex. the `$depth` parameter).