# How to loop through this json decoded data in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I've have this list of products in JSON that needs to be decoded:

```
"[{"productId":"epIJp9","name":"Product A","amount":"5","identifier":"242"},{"productId":"a93fHL","name":"Product B","amount":"2","identifier":"985"}]"
```

After I decode it in PHP with `json_decode()`, I have no idea what kind of structure the output is. I assumed that it would be an array, but after I ask for `count()` it says its "0". How can I loop through this data so that I get the attributes of each product on the list.

Thanks!

Comment: $decoded_json = json_decode($list);, then output the array as echo "<pre>"; print_r($decoded_json); echo "</pre>"; and paste the output here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To convert json to an array use

```
 json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use json_decode() It will convert your json into array.

e.g,

```
$json_array = json_decode($your_json_data); // convert to object array
$json_array = json_decode($your_json_data, true); // convert to array
```

Then you can loop array variable like,

```
foreach($json_array as $json){
   echo $json['key']; // you can access your key value like this if result is array
   echo $json->key; // you can access your key value like this if result is object
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try like following codes:

```
$json_string = '[{"productId":"epIJp9","name":"Product A","amount":"5","identifier":"242"},{"productId":"a93fHL","name":"Product B","amount":"2","identifier":"985"}]';

$array = json_decode($json_string);

foreach ($array as $value)
{
   echo $value->productId; // epIJp9
   echo $value->name; // Product A
}
```

#### Get Count

```
echo count($array); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the manual ?

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Or just find some duplicates ?

> [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Use GOOGLE.

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

Second parameter. If it is true, it will return array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code at php fiddle online, works for me

```
 $list = '[{"productId":"epIJp9","name":"Product A","amount":"5","identifier":"242"},{"productId":"a93fHL","name":"Product B","amount":"2","identifier":"985"}]';

$decoded_list = json_decode($list); 

echo count($decoded_list);
print_r($decoded_list);
```