# Updating multiple rows in mysql using php for a json array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a json array which needs to be parsed in such a way that I can update multiple rows in one mysql query.

This is my json array:

```
[{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1000"}
,{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1001"}
,{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1003"}]
```

I am trying a update query something like this:-

```
$query="UPDATE urd_voucher_table SET voucher_status ='$status', doc_no = '$docNo' WHERE voucher_id ='$vc_id'";
```

I want to know how can I parse the above json in order to get individual values for voucher_status, doc_no and voucher_id.

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Read [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: You need to run loop over json decoded array.

Comment: Thank you @SameerJain can you help with some code.I am new to coding.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Saty

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464457/how-to-loop-through-this-json-decoded-data-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Decode the JSON and loop over the decoded array.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1000"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1001"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1003"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE); // Observe the second parameter. If it is TRUE, associative array will be returned irrespective of what json is.
if (! empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $elem) {
        extract($elem);
        $query="UPDATE urd_voucher_table SET voucher_status ='$voucher_status', doc_no = '$doc_no' WHERE voucher_id ='$voucher_id'";
        // Add your code here.
    }
}
```

Reference of [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode()` it will return an associative array with key, value pair like :

```
    $strJson = '[{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1000"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1001"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1003"}]';
  $arr = json_decode($strJson);
```

will return:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [doc_no] => ADV103 [voucher_status] => closed [voucher_id] => URDV1000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [doc_no] => ADV103 [voucher_status] => closed [voucher_id] => URDV1001 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [doc_no] => ADV103 [voucher_status] => closed [voucher_id] => URDV1003 ) )

now using loop you can fetch data & insert/update database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the json string into an array, loop through the results and run the update query. Please see my example below...

```
$rows = json_decode('[{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1000"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1001"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1003"}]');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $query="UPDATE urd_voucher_table SET voucher_status ='{$row['voucher_status']}', doc_no = '{$row['doc_no']}' WHERE voucher_id ='{$row['voucher_id']}'";
    // ... Run query etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `json_encode()` and then iterate result array in `foreach`. Like following:

```
$jsonString  = '[{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1000"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1001"},{"doc_no":"ADV103","voucher_status":"closed","voucher_id":"URDV1003"}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach($json_decoded as $index=>$val){
    $status = $val->voucher_status;
    $docNo = $val->doc_no;
    $vc_id = $val->voucher_id;
    $query="UPDATE urd_voucher_table SET voucher_status ='$status', doc_no = '$docNo' WHERE voucher_id ='$vc_id'";
    //execute query here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More info on http://www.geeksengine.com/database/data-manipulation/bulk-insert.php

Follow these steps

1. decode json
2. apply foreach loop per record
3. Built and concat data for this part for each record in JSON
   for e.g. `(a,e,r),(br,t,y),(t,y,c);`
4. Hard code this part in query "`Insert into table (c1,c2,c3) VALUES` "
5. And attche data that was created in `step 3`.

Final query will be

```
 Insert into table (c1,c2,c3) VALUES . STEP 3
```