# Fetching JSON data

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I am having issue in fetching JSON data in PHP. Below is my code and JSON file. The issue is that it fetches only first product of JSON and does not iterate through the whole loop.

I know there must be a little mistake due to which it is only fetching first row.

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Test</title> 
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <style>

            .box
            {
                width:750px;
                padding:20px;
                background-color:#fff;
                border:1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius:5px;
                margin-top:100px;
            }
        </style>
      </head>  
      <body>  
            <div class="container box">
                <h3 align="center">Import JSON File Data into Postgresql</h3><br />
                <?php
                $host = "localhost"; // db ip
                $user = "postgres"; // db username (mention your db password here)
                $pass = "postgres";// database password
                $db = "json_order"; // db 
                    // Connecting to my database 
                $connect = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Could not connect to server\n");
                //$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employee"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
                $query = '';
                $table_data = '';
                $filename = "testdata.json";
                $data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
                $array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
                $i=0;
                foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
                {
                            // Make Multiple Insert Query 
                    $query .= "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ('".$row[$i]["id"]."', '".$row[$i]["title"]."')";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                    $table_data .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row[$i]["id"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row[$i]["title"].'</td>
                        </tr>
                    ';                  
                    $i++;
                }
                if(pg_query($connect, $query))  //Run Mutliple Insert Query
                {
                    echo '<h3>Imported JSON Data</h3><br />';

                    echo '
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="45%">ID</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Title</th>
                                </tr>
                    ';
                    echo $table_data;       
                    echo '</table>';
                }




                ?>
                <br />
            </div>  
      </body>  
</html>
```

/////////////////// Json File (testdata.json) /////////////////

```
{  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "id":4790584326,
         "title":"Black Sand"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790581318,
         "title":"Black Sea"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790599046,
         "title":"BLOSSOM MANAMI (02-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790598534,
         "title":"BLOSSOM MANAMI (02-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790587462,
         "title":"Blue Breeze"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790600326,
         "title":"Bow Bells"
      },
      {  
         "id":1008999299,
         "title":"Copy of Product 1"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790601542,
         "title":"Coral Charm"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790588550,
         "title":"Coral spectrum"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790589446,
         "title":"Dazzling Sea"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790600646,
         "title":"Emerald Woo"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790592518,
         "title":"Enchanted Blossom"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790595206,
         "title":"FLORAL SAGA (05-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790595846,
         "title":"FLORAL SAGA (05-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790596678,
         "title":"FLORENTINA (08-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790596422,
         "title":"FLORENTINA (08-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790593030,
         "title":"IMPERIAL BOUQUET (06-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790594630,
         "title":"IMPERIAL BOUQUET (06-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790598150,
         "title":"IRIS INVERSE (03-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790597958,
         "title":"IRIS INVERSE (03-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790585606,
         "title":"Mesmerised Ocean"
      },
      {  
         "id":6517629254,
         "title":"Mesmerising Bouquet"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790591046,
         "title":"Midnight Grandeur"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790599750,
         "title":"MORNING FLOSS (01-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790599366,
         "title":"MORNING FLOSS (01-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790584774,
         "title":"Mother of pearls"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790590662,
         "title":"Nautical Overboard"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790583558,
         "title":"Ocean Punch"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790584006,
         "title":"Opal Muse"
      },
      {  
         "id":9229155654,
         "title":"p1"
      },
      {  
         "id":9256445510,
         "title":"p1"
      },
      {  
         "id":1005959875,
         "title":"Product 1"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790592006,
         "title":"Radiant Rose"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790582278,
         "title":"Rogue Breeze"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790597702,
         "title":"ROSABELLA (04-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790597062,
         "title":"ROSABELLA (04-B)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790581830,
         "title":"Sea News"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790586438,
         "title":"Seaweed lust"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790600966,
         "title":"Spiritual Marvel"
      },
      {  
         "id":8994515974,
         "title":"Stitch My Fabric"
      },
      {  
         "id":1949467075,
         "title":"test4"
      },
      {  
         "id":1949486851,
         "title":"test4"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790582854,
         "title":"Ultramarine"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790591558,
         "title":"Viva Glam"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790594118,
         "title":"WHIMSICAL VINES (07-A)"
      },
      {  
         "id":4790593478,
         "title":"WHIMSICAL VINES (07-B)"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your quick response. I used this loop but it is giving "undefined index" error

Comment: Please do not use looping with I please check this post more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464457/how-to-loop-through-this-json-decoded-data-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `foreach($array as $row)` to loop the JSON data, there is no need to use the `$i` variable, because eache element of the json object will be accessible through the `$row` variable.

**EDIT :**

Also, a Multiple Insert Query should be in this format :

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2), ( Value1, Value2 )....
```

So change your code to this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ";
foreach($array['products'] as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
            {
                        // Make Multiple Insert Query 
                $query .= " ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["title"]."'), ";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                $table_data .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';                  
            }
```

**SECOND EDIT :**

The final query will have an extra `,` in the end of it, so to delete you should do :

```
$theQuery = rtrim($theQuery,", ");
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/41av-x739) .

Comment: Answer already exist in stsckoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464457/how-to-loop-through-this-json-decoded-data-in-php

Comment: That's a part of the answer, in the OP code there is two problems 1) Looping the JSon Data, 2) Creating a multiple insert query

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your timely response. I have tried the above code but still it is showing only the first row

Comment: But that JSON starts with an array. MY JSON's format is a bit different. I have written a code which is working fine on the JSON file which is in your link

Comment: @TalalHaider, That's because there is an extra `,` in the end of the query. I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: @TalalHaider, then, will you honor me and accept this answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
<html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Test</title> 
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <style>

            .box
            {
                width:750px;
                padding:20px;
                background-color:#fff;
                border:1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius:5px;
                margin-top:100px;
            }
        </style>
      </head>  
      <body>  
            <div class="container box">
                <h3 align="center">Import JSON File Data into Postgresql</h3><br />
                <?php
                $host = "localhost"; // db ip
                $user = "postgres"; // db username (mention your db password here)
                $pass = "postgres";// database password
                $db = "json_order"; // db 
                    // Connecting to my database 
                $connect = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or die ("Could not connect to server\n");
                //$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employee"); //Connect PHP to MySQL Database
                $query = '';
                $table_data = '';
                $filename = "testdata.json";
                $data = file_get_contents($filename); //Read the JSON file in PHP
                $array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
                $i=0;
                foreach($array['products'] as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
                {
                            // Make Multiple Insert Query 
                    $query .= "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["title"]."')";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                    $table_data .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                            <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
                        </tr>
                    ';                  
                    $i++;
                }
                if(pg_query($connect, $query))  //Run Mutliple Insert Query
                {
                    echo '<h3>Imported JSON Data</h3><br />';

                    echo '
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="45%">ID</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Title</th>
                                </tr>
                    ';
                    echo $table_data;       
                    echo '</table>';
                }




                ?>
                <br />
            </div>  
      </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
foreach($array->products as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
                {
                            // Make Multiple Insert Query 
                    $query .= "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ('".$row[$i]["id"]."', '".$row[$i]["title"]."')";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                    $table_data .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    ';                  

                }
```

Comment: what do you get when you print_r($array['products']), print_r($array) and print_r($array->products)

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop over products array

```
            $i=0; //remove no need
            foreach($array['products'] as $row)  //change to $array['products']
            {
                        // Make Multiple Insert Query 
                $query .= "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ('".$row["id"]."', '".$row["title"]."')";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                $table_data .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';                  
                $i++;
            }
```

Comment: Still, he'll have a problem with his Query!

Answer (score 0):

The error was that you were accessing an object, not an array
so it access it keys simply as : `$row->id`, and `$row->title`
and that object was nested (an object of objects)
hence the double foreach loop
here is a working [code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/auw5-e5tk) for the display without the database part
Here is a working code based on your code, I just changed the values presentations :

```
 $data='{  
       "products":[  
          {  
             "id":4790597958,
             "title":"IRIS INVERSE (03-B)"
          },
          {  
             "id":4790585606,
             "title":"Mesmerised Ocean"
          },
          {  
             "id":6517629254,
             "title":"Mesmerising Bouquet"
          }
       ]
    }';
    echo "<pre>";
    $array = json_decode($data); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array

    foreach($array as $value) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
    {
        foreach($value as $row){
        $query .= "INSERT INTO order_insert(id,title) VALUES ('".$row->id."', '".$row->title."'), ";      // Make Multiple Insert Query 

                $table_data .= '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';       
        }
    }
```

good luck,

Comment: Thanks but I want to store data in the database too

Comment: @TalalHaider, I know, but you got your array, the rest is easy

Comment: can you please guide me? I am stuck

Comment: @TalalHaider, there you go

Comment: @TalalHaider, I'd like to have some feedback please, if this had work out for you or not