# Convert string to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string:

```
[[{"id":"1"},{"qty":"2"}],[{"id":"2"},{"qty":"1"}],[{"id":"4"},{"qty":"3"}],[{"id":"5"},{"qty":"1"}]]
```

How can I turn it into a multidimensional PHP Array and loop through each id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON encoded string, so just use `json_decode`

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON object. Just use json_decode().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode($json)` in order to do this, using it allows you to obtain an array of objects or if you call json_decode with the second parameter set to false `json_decode($json,TRUE)` you'll obtain just an array.

Here is an example:

```
$str = '[{"id":"1","qty":"2"},{"id":"2","qty":"1"},{"id":"4","qty":"3"},{"id":"5","qty":"1"}]';
$data = json_decode($str);
foreach ($data as $block) {
    echo $block->id."::".$block->qty."<br>";
}

$data = json_decode($str,TRUE);

foreach ($data as $block) {
    echo $block['id']."::".$block['qty']."<br>";
}
```