# how i can pick country_code from this data?

Tags: php, json

here i got this below data with this

```
$location = file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

**and $location contains :**

```
{
      "ip": "77.99.179.98",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "country_name": "United Kingdom",
      "region_code": "H9",
      "region_name": "London, City of",
      "city": "London",
      "zipcode": "",
      "latitude": 51.5142,
      "longitude": -0.0931,
      "metro_code": "",
      "areacode": ""

}
```

have received this data. but am not getting how to pink country_name and region_name from this?

Comment: Did you catch that data in a variable? Then there will be solution with string position function.$location= what a directory or the data after executing your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$obj = json_decode($location, true);
```

then try to get the object

```
echo $obj['country_name'];
```

Comment: True will give u array not a object

Answer (score 0):

you can user [jsone_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) like this

```
    $output_string = '{
      "ip": "77.99.179.98",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "country_name": "United Kingdom",
      "region_code": "H9",
      "region_name": "London, City of",
      "city": "London",
      "zipcode": "",
      "latitude": 51.5142,
      "longitude": -0.0931,
      "metro_code": "",
      "areacode": ""

}';

$arr = json_decode($output_string, true);
echo "Country  Name :".$arr['country_name'];
echo "\nRegion  Name :".$arr['region_name'];
```

see [**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/172065)

Answer (score 0):

```
$locationArray = json_decode($location, true);
echo $locationArray['country_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$arr = json_decode('{
      "ip": "77.99.179.98",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "country_name": "United Kingdom",
      "region_code": "H9",
      "region_name": "London, City of",
      "city": "London",
      "zipcode": "",
      "latitude": 51.5142,
      "longitude": -0.0931,
      "metro_code": "",
      "areacode": ""

}');

echo $arr->country_code . ", " . $arr->country_name;
```

Add a `true` argument to `json_decode($json_string, true)` to return an array instead of an object as above.

```
$arr = json_decode('{
      "ip": "77.99.179.98",
      "country_code": "GB",
      "country_name": "United Kingdom",
      "region_code": "H9",
      "region_name": "London, City of",
      "city": "London",
      "zipcode": "",
      "latitude": 51.5142,
      "longitude": -0.0931,
      "metro_code": "",
      "areacode": ""

}', true);

echo $arr['country_code'] . ", " . $arr['country_name'];
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `$location->country_code;` it will give you country code.

Comment: without decoding how do you access the prop.. file_get_contents returns string

Comment: of course, you need to decode it. I am just giving code for accessing element