# How do I convert a JSON string [{"name":"fieldname":"value":"fieldvalue"}] into array IN PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm useing PHP.  my string is:

```
[{"name":"emailaddress","value":"me@you.com"},
{"name":"familyname","value":"kasjhdf"},{"name":"mothersname","value":"kjh"},
{"name":"motherscellphone","value":"23423423423"},
{"name":"fathersname","value":""},{"name":"fatherscellphone","value":""},
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"24"},
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"26"},
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"25"},
{"name":"childname1.child_name","value":"asd"},
{"name":"childdob1.child_dob","value":"09/08/2015"},
{"name":"childallergies1.child_allergies","value":"asdf"},
{"name":"childinstructions1.child_instructions","value":"a"},
{"name":"childbelongings1.belongings","value":"sawef"},
{"name":"datesAttending","value":""},{"name":"child_name","value":""},
{"name":"child_dob","value":""},{"name":"child_allergies","value":""},
{"name":"child_instructions","value":""},{"name":"belongings","value":""},
{"name":"groupid","value":"zzzz"},{"name":"job_date_id_count","value":"3"},
{"name":"child_count","value":"1"},{"name":"job_group_name_id","value":"83"},
{"name":"job_group_email_id","value":"55"},{"name":"willbill","value":"0"},
{"name":"form_submitted","value":"1"}]
```

I also need to combine the like values like this:

```
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"24"},
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"26"},
{"name":"childdates1.datesAttending","value":"25"},
```

so the array field would be Array `([childdates[0].datesAttending] => 24,26,25 )`

And my Array would be:

```
 Array ( [emailaddress] => me@you.com [familyname] => skadjhf [mothersname] 
=> kjh [motherscellphone] => 234234234343 [fathersname] => [fatherscellphone] => 
234234234324 [child[0] => [0.child_name] => lkjasdf [child[1] => [1.child_name] 
=> sdfwef [child_name] => [child_dob] => [child_allergies] => 
[child_instructions] => [belongings] => [groupid] => zzzz [job_date_id_count] => 
2 [child_count] => 1 [job_group_name_id] => 83 [job_group_email_id] => 55 
[willbill] => 0 [form_submitted] => 1 )
```

Comment: in javascript its json.parse() and in php its json_decode()

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: The language is in the tags.

Comment: `$result = json_decode($json_string,true);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: json_decode gives it another level.  [0], [1].. .and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the JSON in a string variable like,

`$my_json_string = '[{"name":"emailaddress","value":"me@you.com"}...';`

Then use: [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

`$my_json_array = json_decode($my_json_string );`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

All the json functions are found there and described quite simple.

and

[How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array?rq=1)

Once you have the arrays you can look into:

- [PHP Array push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)
- [PHP Array Combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

There are quite a lot of answers on here that explain just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{"name":"abc","age":"20","lastname":"xyz"}';

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

use `json_decode()` function to convert in into array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use code like this to convert your json into array

$myArray = json_decode($decodedText, true);