# decode json array with multiple objects in php

Tags: php, json

I am unable to decode JSON array with multiple objects. any kind of help will be use full.

```
    {  
   "article_details":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ],
   "article":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `$arr = json_decode($yourArray, true);`

Comment: i had gone through above link. but that code is not working it self!!

Comment: Answer can find in this article :)
Resource:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31355640/4275093

Comment: actually i have these values but i want to know how would i pick articles value separately...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode a JSON string, like this:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
                                  ^ When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
```

So your code should be like this:

```
// Here $json is your json string
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_array as $key => $arrays){
    echo $key . "<br />";
    foreach($arrays as $array){
        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
article_details
article_code => 000000000300028156
diff_amnt => 1
article_code => 000000000300028174
diff_amnt => 1
article_code => 000000000300028126
diff_amnt => 1

article
article_code => 000000000300028156
diff_amnt => 1
article_code => 000000000300028174
diff_amnt => 1
article_code => 000000000300028126
diff_amnt => 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
$json = '
{
   "article_details":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ],
   "article":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ]
}';

$key = 'article_code '; // Since your key is 'article_code ' but not 'article_code', I have to do this
$dataObject = json_decode($json);
echo $dataObject->article_details[0]->$key; // This will out put: 000000000300028156 
$dataArray = json_decode($json, true);
echo $dataArray['article_details'][0]['article_code ']; // This will out put: 000000000300028156
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function

```
<?php
$str = '{  
   "article_details":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ],
   "article":[  
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028156 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028174 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      },
      {  
         "article_code ":"000000000300028126 ",
         "diff_amnt ":"1 "
      }
   ]
}';

var_dump(json_decode($str,true));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["article_details"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028156 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028174 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028126 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
  }
  ["article"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028156 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028174 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["article_code "]=>
      string(19) "000000000300028126 "
      ["diff_amnt "]=>
      string(2) "1 "
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `json_decode` is an object with two properties, `article_details` and `article`
each of them is an array of objects.

But the inner object properties have a trailing space, `"article_code "` and `"diff_amnt "`

You can iterate over them as follows

```
$object = json_decode($str);

foreach($object->article_details as $articleDetails){

    print $articleDetails->{"article_code "} . PHP_EOL;
}


foreach($object->article_details as $article){
    print $article->{"diff_amnt "} . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also note that the values have a trailing space.
Either fix where this is coming from or filter the trailing spaces in the `json` string like this

```
$jsonString = str_replace(' "','"',$jsonString);
```

Explicitly removing any trailing spaces before a double quote.
Then accessing the object properties in usual way

```
foreach($object->article_details as $articleDetails){
    print $articleDetails->article_code . PHP_EOL;
}


foreach($object->article_details as $article){
    print $article->diff_amnt . PHP_EOL;
}
```