# Convert a string with array format text to array with numeric values in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get this variable from from-data in postman:

```
$filter = "[234,321,22,4]"
```

but It's an string.

I want to convert `$filter` to this:

```
$filter = [234,321,22,4]
```

It should be an array with numeric type, not string.

Comment: if it's `json` just use `json_decode($filter,true);` to convert it to array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: I have another varaibles and It's not a raw json. I put it in params. I have another inputs like category=5&limit=2&filter=[34,23,12,54]&offset=1

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know json_decode works on variables. working well NOW ;)