# How to transform a string that contains a nested array into an actual array?

Tags: php, string, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find a way to transform a string type variable into an array type variable. To be more precise, what i am looking for is the change this (example):

```
$v = "['1', 'a', ['2', 'b', ['3'], 'c']]";
```

note that this is not a json-formatted string.
into this:

```
$v = ['1', 'a', ['2', 'b', ['3'], 'c']];
```

Note the double-quotes in the first example, $v is a string, not an array, which is the desired effect.

Comment: Second hint: `parse`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: Single quotes aren't valid in JSON, so that won't help here. If you've got PHP array syntax in a string, you'll need to use eval(), as horrible as that is.

Comment: That does not have a valid json schema

Comment: @iainn you're right, json parse didn't help me at all, and simply using eval on it won't work either. i presume it needs some complex combination of parsing and eval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution using `str_replace`(to prepare for decoding) and `json_decode` functions:

```
$v = "['1', 'a', ['2', 'b', ['3'], 'c']]";
$converted = json_decode(str_replace("'",'"',$v));

print_r($converted);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => a
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => b
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

            [3] => c
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$v = "['1', 'a', ['2', 'b', ['3'], 'c']]";

eval("\$v = $v;");

var_dump($v);
```

PS: make sure $v string doesn't contain unexpected code.

Comment: thank you for your answer! the code provided works, but i choose to use Romans' solution to avoid using the eval function

Comment: You're welcome, and you're right about preferring the json_decode solution over eval.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$json = "['1', 'a', ['2', 'b', ['3'], 'c']]";
$json = str_replace("'",'"',$json);
$result_array = json_decode($json); // This is your array
```