# Convert a string into a specified array using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I convert into an array into a specified array to be exact.
Here's my string

```
data={"table":"users","fname":"mil","lname":"minoza","cntct":"09876543212"}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this..

```
Array ( 
    [table] => users 
    [fname] => mil 
    [lname] => minoza 
    [cntct] => 09876543212 
)
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: this string is json or simple string?

Comment: OK my bad. How I can I select users as table when I want to place users in a certain variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$input = 'data={"table":"users","fname":"mil","lname":"minoza","cntct":"09876543212"}';
$data = str_replace('data=', $input);
$data = json_decode(input , true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data='{"table":"users","fname":"mil","lname":"minoza","cntct":"09876543212"}';
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already asked by many people, you can search before you ask the question

Please go through the link.. This will be give solution for your question [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Where's the question of the other people? So that I can see them as well.

Comment: This is one question, like what you have asked 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array