# JSONobj need to be parse in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to parse this json

{"Ko glumi Nikolu Teslu u filmu "The Prestige"?":"Michael Kane","Eros i Amor su jedan drugome:":"unikat","U filmu "Meet Joe Black" koje biće zaposeda telo Brad Pitta?":"Bog","Kako se zove glavni lik u animiranom filmu "Cars"?":"Phoebe The Fast","Otomansko carstvo je drugi naziv za:":"tursko","Kako se zove morderni slang jezik u filmu "A Clockwork Orange"?":"Madhat","Kako se zove saradnik i najbolji prijatelj Sherlocka Holmesa":"James Wallas","U filmu "The Great Dictator" glavnu ulogu igra:":"Michael Douglas","Kako se zove moreuz koji deli Španiju i Maroko:":"morski tesnac Mesina","Glavni lik u animiranom filmu "Ratatouille" je koja životinja?":"pacov","Koja država je 1908. godine prisajedinila Bosnu svojoj teritoriji?":"Italija",""Ipak se kreće" rekao je:":"Arhimed","Koji lik izgovara čuvenu rečenicu "Luke, I am your father."?":"Darth Vader","Ko je režirao film "A Clockwork Orange"?":"Alfred Hitchcock","Koji je prvi dugometražni animirani film koji je napravio studio "Pixar"?":"Toy Story"}

in array like

a[0][0] = Ko glumi Nikolu Teslu u filmu "The Prestige";

a[0][1] = Michael Kane;

etc.

i try some methods but none work for me.

Comment: Nikola Tesla was played by David Bowie in the Prestige, not Michael Kane. ;)

Comment: Your json data looking not valid ? and please reformat your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: Yeah. As IvanBarayev said, your JSON data doesn't seem to have a valid structure.

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: @Drazen Bjelovuk dobro si me nasmejao :D Ovo mi je android vratio kao pitanja koja su se pala u kvizu i odgovore koje je korisnik dao(a ne tacne odgovor), al fora ti je odlicna :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, escape your Json properly.

This should be what you need:

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "Ko glumi Nikolu Teslu u filmu \"The Prestige\"?": "Michael Kane",
    "Eros i Amor su jedan drugome:": "unikat",
    "U filmu \"Meet Joe Black\" koje biće zaposeda telo Brad Pitta?": "Bog",
    "Kako se zove glavni lik u animiranom filmu \"Cars\"?": "Phoebe The Fast",
    "Otomansko carstvo je drugi naziv za:": "tursko",
    "Kako se zove morderni slang jezik u filmu \"A Clockwork Orange\"?": "Madhat",
    "Kako se zove saradnik i najbolji prijatelj Sherlocka Holmesa": "James Wallas",
    "U filmu \"The Great Dictator\" glavnu ulogu igra:": "Michael Douglas",
    "Kako se zove moreuz koji deli Španiju i Maroko:": "morski tesnac Mesina",
    "Glavni lik u animiranom filmu \"Ratatouille\" je koja životinja?": "pacov",
    "Koja država je 1908. godine prisajedinila Bosnu svojoj teritoriji?": "Italija",
    "\"Ipak se kreće\" rekao je:": "Arhimed",
    "Koji lik izgovara čuvenu rečenicu \"Luke, I am your father.\"?": "Darth Vader",
    "Ko je režirao film \"A Clockwork Orange\"?": "Alfred Hitchcock",
    "Koji je prvi dugometražni animirani film koji je napravio studio \"Pixar\"?": "Toy Story"
}';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

$destArray = [];
foreach ($jsonArray as $key => $val) {
    $destArray[] = [0 => $key, 1 => $val];
}

print_r($destArray);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ko glumi Nikolu Teslu u filmu "The Prestige"?
            [1] => Michael Kane
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Eros i Amor su jedan drugome:
            [1] => unikat
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => U filmu "Meet Joe Black" koje biće zaposeda telo Brad Pitta?
            [1] => Bog
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kako se zove glavni lik u animiranom filmu "Cars"?
            [1] => Phoebe The Fast
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Otomansko carstvo je drugi naziv za:
            [1] => tursko
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kako se zove morderni slang jezik u filmu "A Clockwork Orange"?
            [1] => Madhat
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kako se zove saradnik i najbolji prijatelj Sherlocka Holmesa
            [1] => James Wallas
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => U filmu "The Great Dictator" glavnu ulogu igra:
            [1] => Michael Douglas
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kako se zove moreuz koji deli Španiju i Maroko:
            [1] => morski tesnac Mesina
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Glavni lik u animiranom filmu "Ratatouille" je koja životinja?
            [1] => pacov
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Koja država je 1908. godine prisajedinila Bosnu svojoj teritoriji?
            [1] => Italija
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => "Ipak se kreće" rekao je:
            [1] => Arhimed
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Koji lik izgovara čuvenu rečenicu "Luke, I am your father."?
            [1] => Darth Vader
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ko je režirao film "A Clockwork Orange"?
            [1] => Alfred Hitchcock
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Koji je prvi dugometražni animirani film koji je napravio studio "Pixar"?
            [1] => Toy Story
        )

)
```