# Iterate over JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, dictionary

I cannot figure out how to get the following keys/values from the JSON below:

I need to print out in a for loop:

'projects' i.e 'test-project-1'

'datasets' i.e 'dataset1'

'permissions' i.e 'role: WRITER, group: test1@test.com'

```
{
   "projects":{
      "test-project-1":{
         "datasets":{
            "dataset1":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"WRITER",
                  "group":"test1@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset2":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test2@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset3":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test3@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset4":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test4@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset5":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test5@test.com"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "test-project-2":{
         "datasets":{
            "dataset1":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"WRITER",
                  "group":"test1@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset2":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test2@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset3":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test3@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset4":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test4@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset5":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test5@test.com"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried this but the only thing that prints out is "Array".

Something like this does not work:

```
$new_json = {path_to_json};
$new_projects = $new_json['projects'];
foreach ($new_projects as $project) {
    echo $project . "<br>";
    foreach ($new_projects['datasets'] as $datasets){
        echo $datasets . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? How about explain what I can do to elaborate on the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/763197)

```
$json='{
   "projects":{
      "test-project-1":{
         "datasets":{
            "dataset1":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"WRITER",
                  "group":"test1@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset2":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test2@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset3":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test3@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset4":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test4@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset5":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test5@test.com"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "test-project-2":{
         "datasets":{
            "dataset1":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"WRITER",
                  "group":"test1@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset2":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test2@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset3":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test3@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset4":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test4@test.com"
               }
            },
            "dataset5":{
               "permissions":{
                  "role":"READER",
                  "group":"test5@test.com"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}';
$array=  json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array["projects"] as $projectName => $projects)
{
    echo "Project name ".$projectName."<br/>";
    foreach($projects["datasets"] as $databaseNames => $databaseData)
    {
        echo "  Database name ".$databaseNames."<br/>";
        echo "  Database role ".$databaseData["permissions"]["role"]."<br/>";
        echo "  Database group ".$databaseData["permissions"]["group"]."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great! How do I access the 'role' and 'group' data in the nested 'permissions'?

Comment: just use `$databaseData["permissions"]["role"]` or `$databaseData["permissions"]["group"]` you want in the nested for loop where i am printing database name

Comment: Can you update the code demo to reflect that, please? I tried it on my side and it did not work. I'll accept your answer after that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the format is foreach ("array"  as  "key in array")

```
foreach ($new_json as $new_projects) {
    echo $new_projects . "<br>";
    $datasets=$new_projects['datasets'];
    foreach ($new_projects as $datasets){
        echo $datasets . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **json_decode** function [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
foreach($jsonArray as $project){
    echo $project . '<br>';
    foreach($project['datasets'] as $dataset)
    {
        echo $dataset . '<br>';
        foreach($dataset['permissions'] as $permissions)
        {
            echo sprintf('Role: %s, group: %s<br>', $permissions['role'], $permissions['group'];
        }
    }
}
```

if you dont want json to be converted to array, you need to pass false as second argument and stdClass will be returned instead.