# Get only specific code

Tags: php, facebook

In my site user get their own secret code with  access token and submit That code in my site and from this all code I only want to take access token with the help of php...
Check this **ScreenShoot**[ss.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPgAX.jpg)

**Example of access token**   `{"session_key":"5.TVJlCXvhgqdhpA.1497109242.26-100007001746590","uid":100007001746590,"secret":"80cc3dc2ba89e635dcf84b41d6efcc38","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAEa6qMaCj1qCgnOKFHBcfu76C6PrUdK1LnIh39jmabZAdVWmQLO3Ol64ZCXY4388DBfUwksxONGXE5dUY0mK9M07aszl5Qvs8ccqQ39xLEsK2gc1RUJQ0Kqy1ror7R8EPHZCX6pOzX0o4oQAJ1kOq8Oz0n0GysK64ebCsDEokwG36j1awnYaDoJPvOn2AZDZD","machine_id":"-hI8WaLcNeEVUSPuxcEpmhQU","confirmed":true}`

And I also try to separate access token by separating all this code but this actually not working

*Here is my php script*

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $token2 = $_POST['token'];
    if(preg_match("'access_token=(.*?)&expires_in='", $token2, $matches)){
        $token = $matches[1];
            }
    else{
        $token = $token2;
    }
        $extend = get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="  . $token);
```

How to do this and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to get only `access_token` from JSON code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $token2 = $_POST['token'];
    $obj = json_decode($token2);
    echo "Access Token is: <br />". $obj->{'access_token'}; // You can remove it or use this value
    $token = $obj->{'access_token'};
    $extend = get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token="  . $token);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

please try to parse this json into an array using php, then you can collect the token attribute that you need and continue with your validation flow. There is a related link with this solution: [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

There is a basic example:

```
$your_submit_data = '{"session_key":"5.TVJlCXvhgqdhpA.1497109242.26-100007001746590","uid":100007001746590,"secret":"80cc3dc2ba89e635dcf84b41d6efcc38","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAEa6qMaCj1qCgnOKFHBcfu76C6PrUdK1LnIh39jmabZAdVWmQLO3Ol64ZCXY4388DBfUwksxONGXE5dUY0mK9M07aszl5Qvs8ccqQ39xLEsK2gc1RUJQ0Kqy1ror7R8EPHZCX6pOzX0o4oQAJ1kOq8Oz0n0GysK64ebCsDEokwG36j1awnYaDoJPvOn2AZDZD","machine_id":"-hI8WaLcNeEVUSPuxcEpmhQU","confirmed":true}';

$your_array = json_decode($your_submit_data, TRUE);

echo($your_array['access_token']);
```

Best,

Comment: Can you give me one example in my code because I am beginner I recently added ScreenShoot check it

Comment: @kumarchandrasaurav can you please look through the answer may help you as i modified according to your code