# How to read object array object jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

How to parse json Array please help
I have json format like this.
how to output in html using jquery ?

```
{"errors":[{"code":5,"message":"No message content"}],"status":"failure"}{"errors":[{"code":5,"message":"No message content"}],"status":"failure"}
```

Comment: What kind of html ?

Comment: you can add solutions in alert i will do html

Comment: What you have isn't JSON, and it's not a valid object or array either.

Comment: how to read using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

Because of incorrect JSON format you have to convert this data to JSON format. Then JSON format will be like below

```
[
 {
   "errors":[{"code":5,"message":"No message content"}],
   "status":"failure"
 },
 {
   "errors":[{"code":5,"message":"No message content"}],
   "status":"failure"
 } 
]
```

then if we named this json data as `response` you can alert as

```
alert (response[0].status);
```

or

```
   alert (response[0].status + ' : ' +  response[0].errors[0].message);
```