# My array is in json format want to convert in array in codeigniter

Tags: php

```
<?php $user_data_1 = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    echo'<pre>';var_dump($user_data_1);
?>
```

**output**

```
-string(613) "O:11:"User_Entity":21:{s:3:"uid";s:5:"63568";s:6:"roleId";s:1:"5";s:9:"firstName";s:5:"messi";s:8:"lastName";N;s:5:"email";s:17:"kn83446@gmail.com";s:13:"isEmailPublic";s:1:"0";s:6:"mobile";s:10:"0999999999";s:14:"isMobilePublic";s:1:"0";s:8:"password";s:9:"123456789";s:10:"profilePic";N;s:8:"remoteId";s:32:"629e292ad60f19660447a45665c72ca6";s:9:"createdOn";s:10:"1527850240";s:9:"updatedOn";s:10:"1531733425";s:9:"createdBy";s:1:"0";s:9:"UpdatedBy";s:1:"0";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:15:"socialAccountId";s:0:"";s:17:"socialAccountType";s:7:"Website";s:6:"urlkey";N;s:10:"categories";a:0:{}s:13:"isNewWorkshop";N;}"
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is serielized use `unserialize()` function