# Conversion of Json std object into array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have `json` like this :

```
{"status":"TRUE","flag":1,"message":"Has Data","data":[{"country_id":"1","country_name":"India"}]}
```

This is the return value I am getting from api. I need to convert this into array and I need the values country_id and country_name.

I tried to convert using but unable to parse it as array

```
json_decode();
```

but still I am getting in std object format. Someone help me. Thanks in advance.

In model I am returning the values in

```
return $Result->result_array()
```

Comment: Use `json_decode($json, true)` for an associative array. Read the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Because it is an object. But I suppose, you need the 'data' member of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode($json, true)` ;

```
$json = '{"status":"TRUE","flag":1,"message":"Has Data","data":[{"country_id":"1","country_name":"India"}]}';
 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

echo $array['data'][0]['country_id'].PHP_EOL;
echo $array['data'][0]['country_name'];
```

See working demo : https://eval.in/1040313

**Output**

```
1
India
```

Comment: almost works, but I will get more country list inside data, So I can't use

     $array['data'][0]['country_name']

Comment: Anyway I got an Idea from your suggestion, and I solved by using foerach to get country details. Thanks @pradeep

Comment: just loop `$array['data']` to get more , what u provide i give my answer according to it

Comment: glad it helps you happy coding