# Putting a JSON result within []

Tags: php, json

I am trying to add values from a JSON API to a MySQL. The problem is that the result return without the [], so I cannot foreach it and insert all the values to the database.

**This is the API URL**

> http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/Gemini

This is the code I am having

```
$data = file_get_contents(
  "https://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/Gemini", 
  true);

$array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
foreach($array as $row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{
  $query .= "INSERT INTO zodiac(date, horoscope, sunsign, url) 
  VALUES (
    '" . $row["date"]. "', 
    '" . $row["horoscope"]."', 
    '" . $row["sunsign"]."', 
    '" . $row["sunsign"]."'
  ); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
}
```

If I combine $data = "[$data]"; (with and without the quotes) it prints correctly but cannot be parsed as an array. Or at least I cont know how to do it.
I have tried searching for some way to fix that and found some interesting ideas here [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array) but none of them seems to work.

And other way to get the result within []?

Thanks

Comment: They are serving a single object. Not an "array" of objects. I don't understand the question. See [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) perhaps?

Comment: *The problem is that they haven't given me a nail, so I can't use a hammer.* Why do you think you need to use a loop for this?

Comment: @iainn, I guess it is because I do not know any other way to do it.

Comment: @ficuscr, I need it in case I want to pars multiple single objects like {},{},{} for example for 3 days horoscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstood you requirements then this should work for you. I've seen the API response, it is just returning a **single** result for a horoscope. Though I've just used your existing code to make it workable(**which is not recommended to use**), I wish you'll try with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/Gemini",true);
$array[] = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
$query = '';
foreach($array as $key=>$row) //Extract the Array Values by using Foreach Loop
{    
    $query.= "INSERT INTO zodiac(date,horoscope,sunsign,url)
VALUES ('". $row["date"]."','".$row["horoscope"]."','".$row["sunsign"]."','".$row["sunsign"]."'); ";  // Make Multiple Insert Query 
}
echo $query;
?>
```

**With PDO:**

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/Gemini",true);
$array = json_decode($data, true); //Convert JSON String into PHP Array
$sql = "INSERT INTO zodiac (date, horoscope, sunsign) VALUES (:date, :horoscope, :sunsign)";
$stmt= $dpo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
```