# How to get stripe plan json response into array.I am getting the correct response from the stripe as json like this

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments, strip

Problem is I am  not getting array from this json.

```
 Stripe\Plan JSON: {
        "id": "plan_DbP7kQM1OUScdl",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 5000,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1536912374,
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": [],
        "nickname": null,
        "product": "prod_DbP70yDV8qUGND",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: You are getting an array from it? Yes, that is what you usually do with Json. Your "question" is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Andreas i used json_decode()  but not working .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through json_decode

```
$array_val = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

It will return you array.

Comment: I have tested and this is working.

$json_string= '{ "id": "plan_DbP7kQM1OUScdl", "object": "plan", "active": true, "aggregate_usage": null, "amount": 5000, "billing_scheme": "per_unit", "created": 1536912374, "currency": "usd", "interval": "month", "interval_count": 1, "livemode": false, "metadata": [], "nickname": null, "product": "prod_DbP70yDV8qUGND", "tiers": null, "tiers_mode": null, "transform_usage": null, "trial_period_days": null, "usage_type": "licensed" }';

$array_val = json_decode($json_string, true);

print_r($array_val);

Comment: Your Json string is after "Stripe\Plan JSON:"  text not including this text.