# Transform output value to array in php

Tags: php

I need to transform an ouput value in array

I have this output

```
{ "ID":"5454126" ,"class":"ObjectClassRAJ" }
```

I just need to have the ID "5454126" how can i do it please ?

Thanks

Comment: But it isn't php obj

Comment: no it's not how can i do it ? i have a variable that contains $output= { "ID":"5454126" ,"class":"ObjectClassRAJ" }

Comment: Use `json_decode()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: @xzibit15  did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$ch =json_decode($json,true);

echo $ch["ID"];
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/Hsncf

Answer (score 0):

Try json_decode:

```
<?php
$string = '{ "ID":"5454126" ,"class":"ObjectClassRAJ" }';
$obj = json_decode($string);
print_r($obj);
echo "<br>ID: ".$obj->ID;
echo "<br>class: ".$obj->class;
?>
```