# how to create json array in php

Tags: php, json

I want to create an array which response come like this

> response should like this

```
   [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
   }]
```

Comment: use json_encode and json_decode function

Comment: Use `json_encode`

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, I just temporary set same data in for loop.

```
$obj = new \stdClass;
$all = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $obj->name= "test$i";
    $obj->data = [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175];
    $all[] =  $obj;
}
echo json_encode($all);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `json_encode` function

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array in php then use json_encode function. it will convert the array to json format. Similarly, json_decode function will convert the json values to array or object.

here you will get the relavent help -

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach ($sNames as $key => $name) {
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $services[$key] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'data' => $sData[$key],
            );
        }
    }
    $data['services'] = json_encode($services);
```

i think you have to do something like this, may be this will help you.