# POST request from JS to PHP: wrong JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

When Im sending post request to php - it return string to me and I can't do anything with it.

That's my request from JS:

```
axios.post("ajax.php", JSON.stringify(myObj))
```

That's how I get data (from JS) in PHP:

```
$data = $_POST;
```

And that's response of $data var_dump

```
array(1) {
  ["{"username":"rew","info":"rew"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I need 2 variables. First **username** and second **info**. How can I do it? Is it possible to split this line? Or I sending in wrong format?

My full PHP code

```
$data = array(
  "userName" => $_POST['userName'],
  "pass" => $_POST['pass']
);
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data),
    'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                 "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                 "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
echo $file;
```

And var myObj

```
let myObj = {
    "username": "rew",
    "info": "rew"
};
```

Comment: use json_decode function. More info is  here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you don't need to `stringify` the object. The default content-type with `axios` is going to be `application/json`, so this should work:

```
axios.post("ajax.php", myObj);
```

As to `$_POST` will only come content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`, you need to change your code to decode raw input:

```php
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: I thought so too. But in this case it returns empty array. json_decode returns null.

Comment: Can you update your question with `myObj` example and php code you use?

Comment: @AleksKharchenko you making it too complex, don't use `$_POST` here. Or it is a requirement?

Comment: With 'php://input' - it's working, finally I get right JSON :)
No, it's not requirement, I'm just was looking for right solution