# JSON to PHP array error - Angular frontend and Codeiginiter php as backend

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im using angular as front end and  php for backend.
Angular array im sending through http

```
[{
name:'yogesh',
age :'30',
role:'developer'
}
]
```

but in php it is converted as

```
[
{ name:'yogesh'},
{age :'30'},
{role:'developer'}
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7512040/2275490; note: no leading '[' and trailing ']'

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON. You have to pass a valid JSON and use `json_decode` in PHP to convert it to the array. Check the link and click on execute code to check result:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b0e191862728cd444a9eb575564078d1e0af57d

```
$arr = '{
"name":"yogesh",
"age" :"30",
"role":"developer"
}';

$arr = json_decode($arr, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: @Yogeshkumar check the updated answer. It is working fine.