# How to convert a nested JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, json, var-dump

I need to convert

h
**this**  JSON:

```
["theory",["theory","theory of relativity","theory test","theory of everything","theory definition","theory of evolution","theory of mind","theory of a deadman","theory of love","theory meaning"]]
```

to a array, including nesting, in PHP:

```
array (
  0 => 'theory',
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'theory',
    1 => 'theory of relativity',
    2 => 'theory test',
    3 => 'theory of everything',
    4 => 'theory definition',
    5 => 'theory of evolution',
    6 => 'theory of mind',
    7 => 'theory of a deadman',
    8 => 'theory of love',
    9 => 'theory meaning',
  ),
)
```

Once converted to an object in PHP I need to be able to access / find the "theory of relativity" in the object.

Comment: Have a look at the php docs for json_decode https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You should use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Example:

```
$myJson = '["theory",["theory","theory of relativity","theory test","theory of everything","theory definition","theory of evolution","theory of mind","theory of a deadman","theory of love","theory meaning"]]';

print_r(json_decode($myJson));
```

Q: how to access to "theory of relativity" ?:

A:

```
$data = json_decode($myJson);
echo $data[1][1];
```

Comment: how to access to "theory of relativity" ?