# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object {"exception":"[object]

Tags: php, laravel

i have a $data= `[{"id":54,"systemid":"1610000060000000063"}]`and i am trying to get id like this
`$id = $data['id']` and even i tried `$data->id` and i am getting Trying to get property 'id' of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'id' of non-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an array in json format:

```
 $array='[{"id":54,"systemid":"1610000060000000063"}]';
```

first you have to decode the array:

```
$decodedArray=json_decode($array);
```

then get the element at index 0:

```
$object=$decodedArray[0];
```

then you can get it's id:

```
$id=$object->id;
```

see [the sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/n6ctw?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=) for it: